# Does Apache need to be stopped to edit "/etc/apache2/sites-available/default"?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, default

I am attempting to edit the "default" file located at ..

```
"/etc/apache2/sites-available/default"
```

on my Ubuntu machine running Apache 2.2.8.

I want to do this in order to enable the use of .htaccess files. I have downloaded the "default" file and edited it and now I am trying to upload it back to the server via SFTP. I keep getting permission denied errors.

Could it be because Apache is running and making use of the file? I am an admin on the machine so I would expect to be able to overwrite the file. Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it does not need to be stopped.

Try accessing the file through `ssh`, and make sure you access it with root privileges:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

You would still need to `force-reload` Apache after changing the config files, as tux21b suggested in a comment below:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 force-reload
```

Comment: and don't forget to force-reload (or restart) afterwards. Otherwise your changes won't be applied.

Answer (score -2):

For Apache/2.4.7 , the file that you want to edit is:

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```