# ZendFramework: /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

Tags: zend-framework, apache2, default

Site was working perfect then I edited the default file (/etc/apache2/sites-available/default). Edited directory and directory root. Now my webpage wont load anymore. I changed it back to what it was before and now it wont load my website. When I did an edit, the default file type may have changed.

What is the file type of the default file? Is it a .txt?
Also, made a change in zenserver_gui.conf and then set it back to what it was before.

I think I may have changed the file type for  the default file. I tried restarting the server and apahce2 no luck.

ALso did this [Does Apache need to be stopped to edit "/etc/apache2/sites-available/default"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473515/does-apache-need-to-be-stopped-to-edit-etc-apache2-sites-available-default)

Still not working. Any ideas?

Comment: What is your current default file configs?

Comment: All I was changing was the document root path. Then I changed it back and saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site I had was hacked. They got root access. Disabled all commands.